# select where con ajax (laravel)

Tags: laravel, ajax, select

saben que a través de un ajax, relleno una DataTable el tema es que he modificado unas cosas y ahora necesito que en la tabla me muestre solo algunos usuarios,en la tabla (DB) existe una columna llamada ID_ROL, el cual necesito que solo me muestre los usuarios con ID_ROL = 2, (ya que esa pertenece al rol alumno), el tema es que nose como hacerlo con ajax (la consulta), espero su ayuda por favor

AJAX

```js
<script>

 $(document).ready( function () {


 var id_alumno = "id";
 var rut_alumno = "rut";
 var nombre_alumno = "nombre";
 var apellido_alumno = "apellido";
 var edad_alumno = "edad";
 var email_alumno = "email";
  var rol_alumno = "id_rol";

 var botones = '<div class="btn-group elevation-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success"><i class="fas ion-ios-eye" style="width: 20px;"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info"><i class="fas ion-ios-create" style="width: 20px;"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger"><i class="fas ion-md-trash" style="width: 20px;"></i></button></div>';    


 $('#listaAlumnos').DataTable
  ({
  'paging'       : true,
  'lengthChange' : true,
  'searching'    : true,
  'ordering'     : true,
  'processing'   : true,
  'info'         : true,
  'autoWidth'    : true,
  'language'     : lenguage_es,
  'responsive' : true,
  'serverSide' : true,
  'responsive' : true,
  'ajax'     :"{{ url('api/tabla_alumnos') }}",
  'columns'  : [
        {data: id_alumno},
        {data: rut_alumno},
        {data: nombre_alumno},
        {data: apellido_alumno},
        {data: edad_alumno},
        {data: email_alumno},
        
        {defaultContent: botones, "width": "90px"}
        ],
 });
 });
</script>
```

ROUTE API

```js
Route::get('tabla_alumnos', function (){
 return datatables()
  ->eloquent(App\User::query())
  ->toJson();
});
```

> Hasta el momento el codigo tal cual me muestra todos los usuarios de esa tabla.
>   Gracias.

Comment: ¿No entiendo la pregunta?, la duda es como construir la consulta?

Comment: Si amigo, perdon no lo especifique

Comment: lo hare ahora y te digo

Comment: eso era amigo u.u era algo tan simple, gracias por tomarte tu tiempo y decirme :c, si pudieras poner como respuesta para que la coloque como respuesta seria ideal